# Index with OR condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a query similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM User
WHERE Name = 'Username1' OR Name = 'Username2'
```

When I execute it and take a look at the execution plan, I see that there is one `NonClustered Index Seek` with `Number of executions = 1` and one `Key Lookup` with `Number of executions = 2` which is fine because it found 2 results.

But I don't understand how it can search for 2 different values in index at the same time. It is logical to me that `NonClustered Index Seek` is executed 2 times. Once for `Username1` and once for `Username2`. Because those values are in different parts in index tree, how is it possible to search more values with one index seek?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to think of query execution order  from left to right,once you understood this,then things will be more simple..

Below is a quote from Paul White on the same:[Iterators, Query Plans, and Why They Run Backwards](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/05/iterators-query-plans-and-why-they-run-backwards.aspx)

> Execution of a query plan starts at the root, and flows down the plan via a series of nested method calls.  Data is pulled up the plan in the reverse direction: from the leaves toward the root, a row at a time.

**It is logical to me that NonClustered Index Seek is executed 2 times.**

Clustered index seek operator is not executed twice(but nested loops is),since storage engine remembers the initial seek position and then tries to find another value..if the value is on same page then zero read,if it is on another page,then one more read

see my question on dba.se for more info:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134172/set-statistics-i-o-for-nested-loops